# bxslider adds a width of 1366px to slided element even if setup smaller with css

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I am trying to implement bxslider to make my content slide!

Even if my content div is written

```
<div id="content">
```

bxslida will convert it to some

```
<div id="content" style="width: 715%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-1366px, 0px, 0px);">
```

and eventually add some more

```
<div class="bx-clone" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 1366px;">
```

**...and it sucks because it provides a new width of 1366px, even if my content div is correctly setup at 960px with CSS.**

Any idea of what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `slideWidth: 960` when calling `bxSlider`? Please could you post all the code necessary for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: not the best option, but if you add "!important" to your css, your 960 width should override the 1366.  Still, I'm having a tough time picturing the exact issue that's happening. http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Comment: thanks guys i should have figured it out! well, it still adds some odd bx-clone div which is floated, and it messes a bit with code up